# How should you review past items from an iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pattern-matching, iterable

While trying to answer a question on Code Review, I realized my solution was flawed. The code passes the first test for which it was created, but then a second test proves that it does not always work. Certain sequences can be partially matched and then prevent a proper match from succeeding.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    """Source: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149867"""
    print('PASS' if contains((0, 1, 3, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4)) else 'FAIL')
    print('PASS' if contains((1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1, 3)) else 'FAIL')


def contains(iterable, sequence):
    """Determine if sequence can be found in iterable and return the result."""
    offset, length = 0, len(sequence)
    for item in iterable:
        if item == sequence[offset]:
            offset += 1
            if offset == length:
                return True
        elif offset:
            offset = 0
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How should the `contains` function be modified so that it properly works with any given iterable?

Comment: To be clear, both these examples should return `'PASS'` yes?

Comment: You could convert both `sequence` and `iterable` to strings then do a simple `in` test; it's not very memory efficient (but should be fast)

Comment: @Chris_Rands and clever. +1

Comment: @Chris_Rands Are you familiar with the iterables produced by `itertools.count`, `itertools.cycle`, or `itertools.repeat`? Some iterators never come to an end. How do you propose converting such an iterator into a string?

Comment: Eh, if you have an infinite generator when your test will never finish (for `'FAIL'`) whatever approach you take?

Comment: That is correct. If the test is part of a monitor or server that is always supposed to be running, such a process may be required. Otherwise, another system enforcing a timeout may be required.

Comment: Right, well the best solution depends on the use context of course, maybe add these details to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the original (broken) solution is that the algorithm should rewind back to an earlier place in the iterable's data stream if a partial match occurs and then a failure. Some languages allow their iterators to be rewound, but Python does not since iterators are allowed to have unbounded lengths. By introducing an iterator wrapper having history, the original code needs only slight modification.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import collections


def main():
    """Source: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149867"""
    print('PASS' if contains((0, 1, 3, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4)) else 'FAIL')
    print('PASS' if contains((1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1, 3)) else 'FAIL')
    print('PASS' if not contains((1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1, 3)) else 'FAIL')


def contains(iterable, sequence):
    """Determine if sequence can be found in iterable and return the result."""
    offset, length = 0, len(sequence)
    iterator = IteratorWithHistory(iterable, length - 1)
    for item in iterator:
        if item == sequence[offset]:
            offset += 1
            if offset == length:
                return True
        elif offset:
            iterator.rewind(offset)
            offset = 0
    return False


class IteratorWithHistory:

    """IteratorWithHistory(iterable, history_size) -> New Instance"""

    def __init__(self, iterable, history_size):
        """Initialize a new instance of the class."""
        self.__iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.__history = collections.deque((), history_size)
        self.__offset = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        """Return the iterator object itself."""
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Return the next item from the container."""
        if self.__offset:
            item = self.__history[-self.__offset]
            self.__offset -= 1
        else:
            item = next(self.__iterator)
            self.__history.append(item)
        return item

    def rewind(self, offset):
        """Rewind the iterator back by the offset value."""
        if not isinstance(offset, int):
            raise TypeError('offset must be of type int')
        if offset < 1:
            raise ValueError('offset must be a positive number')
        new_offset = self.__offset + offset
        if new_offset > len(self.__history):
            raise ValueError('cannot rewind that far back')
        self.__offset = new_offset


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change my approach entirely like so:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    """Source: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149867"""
    print('PASS' if contains((0, 1, 3, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4)) else 'FAIL')
    print('PASS' if contains((1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1, 3)) else 'FAIL')


def contains(iterable, sequence):
    """Determine if sequence can be found in iterable and return the result."""
    length = len(sequence)
    if length > len(iterable):
        return False
    else:
        upper_bound = len(iterable) - length
        for i in range(upper_bound + 1):
            if iterable[i:i + length] == sequence:
                return True
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instead of checking one item as a time, I am checking to see if a slice of the *mother* list of lenght `len(sequence)` is identical to the `sequence`. `upper_bound` controls the number of checks that are required.

PS: They both return `"PASS"`.

Comment: This solution will not work if given an iterable that does not support indexing.

Comment: An open file is also an iterable... How would you apply that there?

Comment: It does not really matter what I would do. Answers are supposed to be generic enough to help anyone, not just the person who asked the question.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower What I meant is that a solution that covers **all** iterables probably does not exist. You have to be more specific on what you want to apply this function to.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41724649/216356) not satisfy the question for all iterables?

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested with "all iterables" but tried to use idioms that should work

**edited** per comment's new requirement: (looks like just one larger scope try/except works)

```
a, b = (2, ), (2, 1)
def contains(a, b):      
    # a may be "any iterable", using generator to access
    ag = (i for i in a)    
    try:
    # initialize history with 1st len(b) elements of a
        history = [next(ag) for _ in b] 

        while True: # exits with a match or a StopIteration exception

        # check if all elements in iterables: history, b are equal
        # independent of b container type
        # deMorgan logic in list comprehension to "and" matches, 
        # list comprehension returns [] if every element matches
            if not [1 for j, e in zip(history, b) if j != e]:
                return True
        # advance history contents        
            history.pop(0) 
            history.append(next(ag))

    except StopIteration:
        return False
```

and yes I have read that pop(0) is inefficient

Comment: Your code fails for the following test case: `print('PASS' if not contains((1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1, 3)) else 'FAIL')`

Comment: not one of the test cases, but yes, it isn't guarded for len(sequence) < len(iterable) ,  another try/except StopIteration could wrap my history intialization if that is part of the spec

Comment: fixed, but perhaps you should update the question with any additional required test cases